# Parse and predict tsv values for Highcharts gantt

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, csv

I have to build a small management dashboard that consists of several parts. Most of them were no problem, but on the current page I got completely stuck.

**Explanation:**
I have used an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15026060/highcharts-gantt-chart-plot-issue) that I have found and some examples in the Highcharts forum to build my [own chart](http://www2.hs-esslingen.de/~sakuwi00/hc/).
The basic function is working, I am getting my data from a tsv file, building the arrays and displaying them.

Now comes the tricky part and I am not able to get my head around it…

The data I'm getting is live data from SAP and is the record of current production processes. *(The provided dataset is a finished one, but later I want to display the actual live data.)*

Since it is a pilot there is no chance to access the SAP database at the moment and I have to handle the data in tsv format.

There are 3 different states for each package.
**B10**: **start**
**B30**: **pause**
**B40**: **stop**

At the moment I am just separating all working packages and printing them, but according to the management here there are many functionalities missing.

**Prerequisite:** *Refresh every x seconds*

What they want *(the easy version)*:
If one of the processes gets a B10, its starts “running” and its bar should get green. If there is no B30 in the next rows, the last point get’s the current time as “now” and is extending **(the bar is growing)**.
If there is a B30, the process should “pause”, the color of the bar should change to red (including data points of that process) and only continue if there comes another B10. Between B30 and the new B10 there are no datapoints.
On B40 the process simply stops and turns grey again.

**My problem:** I have no single idea how I should analyze the “future” data (next steps). Should I separately run through the tsv again and check it for occurrences of B30 or B40 in advance? What’s making my life even more complicated is that two independent processes could run at the same time (for ex. Process 1 and Process 40). Also an indicator line should “run” to indicate the current time.

What they want in the future *(or how I call it: nightmare)*:
2 or even more persons could work at the same process, but they always want to see just one bar per process… In the case of multiple operators it also has to be true that all operators have to set their status to B30, otherwise the process will not interrupted.
They further want to zoom into the current day with only the processes of the day, and if a process (for example 40) is started in “advance”, it should appear in the same zoom level. The processes for the day and a schedule will be provided in a separated file and I have to compare my data points to the schedule.

I know, it’s a weird explanation for a weird request. I also don't want anyone to give me a finished product, but I have to develop this here by myself and I just got a real problem with the logic. If I didn't explain well enough or there are further questions, please ask me and I will answer immediately.

Comment: Information about B10: start B30: pause B40: stop are printed in the single tsv or always it is separated file? Have you example of these files?

Comment: Hey Sebastain! The tsv is linked on the example page I have posted above. Here is the link again: http://www2.hs-esslingen.de/~sakuwi00/hc/

Comment: And this file is updated each time, am I right or it static?

Comment: It's updated like every five minutes. And the file provided is a full process, in a running process many of the lines will not yet be present.

Comment: Only what comes to my mind is get file, set colors of each elements, keep all in the any array (maybe) then, wait for next call. If you receive then add points, update colors. But honestly im nor sure how to "predict" data.

Comment: Thx for your advice. I was actually thinking about paring the file a second time to "predict" the future and then assign colors and stuff, but since i would have to do that in many different stages i just don't get my head around it. I think i will get me a whiteboard tomorrow and start drawing.
Edit: And the idea with a big array that contains the whole file (pseudo database) is good, thanks!

Comment: Hope that helps, but you need to develop your own logic with "predicting" because global array was only my idea.

Comment: Hey Sebastian, I know that but I have to thank you anyway! It was just the small hint I needed, there is noone to talk with and sometimes I am just stuck.Today I managed to read in the arrays and break them into groups and now I can start comparing and assigning. I will report the progress.

Comment: Sounds great, honeslt Im curious if it is possible, so let me know if you achieve this point.